# Neo4 SDN 4 and counters

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

In order to denormilize the data at my Neo4j SDN4 application I have introduced `totalChildDecisions` counter:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Decision {
    private Integer totalChildDecisions = 0; 
}

@Override
@Transactional
public Decision create(String name, String description, String url, String imageUrl, boolean downloadImage, Long parentDecisionId, User user) {

    Decision parentDecision = null;

    if (parentDecisionId != null) {
        parentDecision = lock(parentDecisionId, true);
    }

    decisionDaoValidator.validateDecisionAlreadyExistsByName(name, parentDecision);

    description = HtmlUtils.sanitizeHTML(description);

    Decision decision = createOrUpdate(new Decision(name, description, url, imageUrl, multiVotesAllowed, parentDecision, user), user);

    if (downloadImage) {
        updateImage(decision, imageUrl, downloadImage);
    }

    criterionGroupDao.create(CriterionGroupDaoImpl.DEFAULT_CRITERION_GROUP_NAME, null, decision, user);
    characteristicGroupDao.create(CharacteristicGroupDaoImpl.DEFAULT_CHARACTERISTIC_GROUP_NAME, null, decision, user);

    return decision;
}
```

`lock` method invokes the following repository method:

```
@Query("MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE d.id = {decisionId} SET d._lock = {lock} RETURN d")
Decision lock(@Param("decisionId") Long decisionId, @Param("lock") boolean lock);
```

I'm increasing the `totalChildDecisions` counter inside `Decision` constructor:

```
public Decision(String name, String description, String url, String imageUrl, Decision parentDecision, User author) {
    if (parentDecision != null) {

        addParentDecision(parentDecision);
        parentDecision.addChildDecision(this);

        parentDecision.setTotalChildDecisions(parentDecision.getTotalChildDecisions() + 1);
    }
}
```

`createOrUpdate` invokes `repository.save` method.

Based on this code I'm importing data into my database.

Right now I don't understand why the `totalChildDecisions` differs from the real child decision number inside my Neo4j database(for example I have 2000 child decisions but the counter after each data import shows different values.. like 1998, 1995 and so on). How to correctly obtain the lock on `parentDecision`  in order to properly update its `totalChildDecisions`  counter ?

**UPDATED**

Also, I'm calculating(increasing additional counter) `Decision.totalViews` when User requests a `Decision` from UI. I'm reading the `Decision`, increasing `totalViews` counter on this Decision and saving this Decision. In case of a parallel job(described at the question above) that updates `totalChildDecisions` at the same time I noticed a long time response for my `getDecision()` method because the decision was locked by another job and `getDecision()` was unable to update `totalViews` counter before this job complete.

Taking this into account is it a good idea to update `totalViews` counter async(for example fire the new event from `getDecision()` and update `totalViews` at the ActiveMQ consumer) in order to not block getDecision method ?

Comment: My guess is that you don't unlock the node (you only set `d._lock = true`) and 2nd and following lock query actually won't acquire the lock because it does not cause a write.

Comment: So I have to add unock statement at the end of my method? And if the first query acquire the lock and doesn't realese.. how the other queries can do this with the current implementation ? How it is working now?

Comment: Ok, so it seems that even writing the same value will take the lock, so there must be something else wrong here. Have a look at this example: https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-sdn-ogm-issue-report-template/blob/so-44746742/so-44746742/src/test/java/org/neo4j/sdn/test/SdnTestCase.java#L102

Comment: @frant.hartm thanks, I'll test it ! Could you please also comment on the updated part of my question ?

Comment: @frant.hartm thanks, based on you example I have added unlock logic and now everything is working fine. Also, after that I ran into the strange issue with a default SDN4 `repository.count()` method. At some point of time it started to return 0 or 1 instead of a real number of entities. I have replaced default `count()` implementation with a repository method with a Cypher query: `MATCH (d:Decision) RETURN count(d)` and now this logic started working fine. What could be the reason for this ?